# Not able to sign up for Google Labs: SMS Channels

Tags: sms

I am not able to Sign up for Google SMS Channels, I am getting this error message:

[image: Not able to use Google SMS Channels]

What's wrong? What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SMS Channel was apparently stopped a while back as I was facing the same problem and a mail from the help desk of Google had content informing that since no progress is happening from Labs to a revenue generating effort into mainstream, they are discontinuing it.

So theres a chance that it might not be working for the same reason.

Or, maybe because you entered the wrong number :P

Comment: You have any link of any trusted source which says so?

Comment: search for "Google labs shutdown"